# Rails/3 - Render partial based on state of instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

Struggling with this one a little bit. I have two parameter search form, when both fields match it returns the row into @person:

So what i want to happen is render one partial before the search, another one if a person is matched and another one if a record is not found.

Where does this logic go and what can I check against?

```
def index
  if params[:id] && params[:dob]
    @person = Person.where("id = ? and dob = ?", params[:id], params[:dob]).first
  end
end
```

In my index.html.haml

```
-if ! @person.nil
  =render :partial => 'found'
-elsif @person.nil
  =render :partial => 'not_found'
-else
  =render :partial => 'welcome'
```

Problem is that @person.nil? is always true, whether a search is done or not. Anyone have any ideas what to do? What am I missing?

Comment: Also, please be sure to copy-paste your source code exactly. `elif` in your view is not valid Ruby, indicating that this was likely hand-typed ;) As does the missing paren at the end of line 3 of the controller bit. Oh, and `@person.nil` would be an attribute. Did you mean `@person.nil?`? It's hard to answer a code question when it's likely not the code in question.

Comment: @Matchu, judging by the .haml extension of index.html.haml, looks like he is using HAML. A quick check of the HAML docs - http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_ - looks like it is possibly valid, though I don't know enough about HAML to know if it is correct.

Comment: @Nate Pinchot - I'm familiar with HAML :) The issue here is that lines starting with `-` are essentially `<% %>` in ERb, so the fact that `elif` and `@person.nil` are not valid Ruby becomes an actual issue.

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors. Sorry about that, long day and didn't have the code available for pasting. My bad. Thanks to everyone for taking a look at my slop ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the @person nevertheless

```
def index
  if params[:id] && params[:dob]
    @person = Person.where("id = ? and dob = ?", params[:id], params[:dob])
  else
    @person = false
  end
end
```

This way you don't have problems with nil and checking if it's nil.

In your view you can just check if @person is false or if size is larger than zero.

```
-if @person
  -if @person.size > 0
    =render :partial => 'found'
  -else
    =render :partial => 'not_found'
  -end
-else
  =render :partial => 'welcome'
-end
```